# Real VNC installer for Linux won't run on PI4 Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: vnc

I'm a newbie so I might be missing something pretty simple.  But, when I go to RealVNC.com and download the installation file to Downloads, extract it and try to run it, it doesn't do anything.

Double-clicking in the file manager, dragging the file into terminal, trying to launch from the Terminal all has zero response.

I thought I might have a buggy version or corrupted SD so I reflashed and updated & upgraded Ubuntu.

I had run Bullseye with no problem here.  Is Ubuntu just buggy in PI?  If so, is there more stable OS?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that RealVNC hasn´t caught up yet with the advances in 23.10.
I have tried the Raspberry VNC connect and that doesn´t work.  The only other Linux RealVNC is for AMD devices.  Will have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

guess we will have to wait? Just got it running on my pi 5